# Printing dictionary from inside a list puts one character on each line

Tags: python, json

Yes, yet another. I can't figure out what the issue is. I'm trying to iterate over a list that is a subsection of JSON output from an API call.

This is the section of JSON that I'm working with:

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "2017-02-22 17:20:29 UTC",
        "description": "",
        "id": 1,
        "label": "FOO",
        "name": "FOO",
        "title": "FOO",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-04 16:37:09 UTC"
    }
]
```

The code that I'm running that retrieves this and displays it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import sys
try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    print "Please install the python-requests module."
    sys.exit(-1)

SAT_API = 'https://satellite6.example.com/api/v2/'
USERNAME = "admin"
PASSWORD = "password"
SSL_VERIFY = False   # Ignore SSL for now

def get_json(url):
    # Performs a GET using the passed URL location
    r = requests.get(url, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD), verify=SSL_VERIFY)
    return r.json()

def get_results(url):
    jsn = get_json(url)
    if jsn.get('error'):
        print "Error: " + jsn['error']['message']
    else:
        if jsn.get('results'):
            return jsn['results']
        elif 'results' not in jsn:
            return jsn
        else:
            print "No results found"
    return None

def display_all_results(url):
    results = get_results(url)
    if results:
        return json.dumps(results, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

def main():
    orgs = display_all_results(KATELLO_API + "organizations/")
    for org in orgs:
        print org

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I appear to be missing a concept because when I print `org` I get each character per line such as

```
[




{







"
c
r
e
a
t
e
d
_
a
t
"
```

It does this through to the final `]`

I've also tried to print `org['name']` which throws the `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python` error. This makes me think that `org` is being seen as a list rather than a dictionary which I thought it would be due to the `[{...}]` format.

What concept am I missing?

**EDIT:** An explanation for why I'm not getting this: I'm working with a script in the [Red Hat Satellite API Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.3/html/api_guide/sect-api_guide-running_queries_using_python) which I'm using to base another script on. I'm basically learning as I go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display_all_results` is returning a string since you are doing [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) in `json.dumps(results, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`,  which converts the dictionary to a string (you are getting that dictionary from `r.json()` in `get_json` function)

You then end up iterating over the characters of that string in `main`, and you see one character per line

Instead just return `results` from `display_all_results` and the code will work as intended

```
def display_all_results(url):
    #results is already a dictionary, just return it
    results = get_results(url)
    if results:
        return results
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I'm not familiar with `json.dumps` (or most of python for that matter) so that was the concept I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Orgs is a result of json.dump which produces a string. So instead of this code:

```
for org in orgs:
    print(org)
```

replace it with simply:

```
#for org in orgs:
print(orgs)
```